# GIT - undo specific past merge but need the commits made after that merge to be intact

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-revert, git-cherry-pick

I was working simultaneously on a *Feature* branch and *Master* branch.

Few days ago I merged my *Feature* into *Master*. A few commits have been made on top of that too.

But later I realised that the feature is no more desired. So I need to remove the commits which have been incorporated due to the *Feature* branch.

On checking, I realised that I have 3 options *Rebase*, *Revert* and *Cherry-pick*.

I might need the commits of the *Feature* branch in future. Therefore, it's commits need to be visible in commit history/ git log etc, if I need them in the future. Hence, I am confused which option of the above three to pick.

Note: All the commits are pushed to master. So would that have any implications on the option I pick?

Comment: You want to keep the commits on the Feature branch, and remove the merged commits on the Master branch?

Comment: Revert. And if you need the changes again, revert the reversion again.

Comment: @ThiepLV I want the commits of the Feature branch to be preserved. Just in case i need them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your branch is already published, you probably want to avoid using an interactive rebase as a solution.  The interactive rebase would allow you to literally excise the `Feature` commits from `Master` which you don't want.  But this would happen at the cost of rewriting the history of `Master`, which can have negative implications.

I think the best option for you would be to `git revert` the `Feature` commits which you do not want.

Use:

```
git revert <SHA-1>
```

where `<SHA-1`> is a commit you want to revert.  If you have a series of commits in order, then you can use:

```
git revert --no-edit <SHA-1>..<SHA-1>
```

using a range of two commits.

There is no way to have the commits in your history for later use.  Either the commits are there, or they are not.

If you want to bring back the commits later, you can either merge or cherry-pick them in, or you could also revert the revert commits (@1615903).

Comment: Thanks. Worked just fine. Though I had to fix 1 conflict, I had originally got that conflict when I used to merge the 'Master' branch into the 'Feature' branch from time to time.